# How to pass an object to mapping function in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am new to this so any help is much appreciated.

I would like to add a new column to a data frame that is a function of both values in the data frame and a python object.

The format is as follows:

```
df['col_3'] = list(map( function, df['col_1'], df['col_2'],instance_of_class ))

def function(a,b,instance):
     return a + b + instance_of_class.attribute
```

where one of the parameters needs to be an instance of a class.

When I do this, python throws an error that the object is non-iterable, I assume this is because it wants only lists passed as parameters. Not sure how to get around this without substantially slowing things down. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with map or apply, but since you are just starting why don't you keep it simple?

```
col_3 = []
for c1, c2 in df[['col_1', 'col_2']].values:
    c3_list.append(function(c1, c2, instance))

df['col_3'] = col_3
```